# how to covert substrings of a list into one single sting

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, concatenation

I generated a list of tuples into a list.Then i wanted to remove all the tupple brackets and convert the whole list into one single list of a string.I tried doing this:

```
from itertools import permutations
l=[]
m=[]
perm = permutations([2,3,5,7], 4)
for i in list(perm):
    #print (i)
     l.append(i)
for data in l:
    k=("%s, %s, %s, %s" % data)
    m.append(k) 
o=' '.join(m)
print(o)
```

the result is :

```
2, 3, 5, 7 2, 3, 7, 5 2, 5, 3, 7 2, 5, 7, 3 2, 7, 3, 5 2, 7, 5, 3 3, 2, 5, 7 3, 2, 7, 5 3, 5, 2, 7 3, 5, 7, 2 3, 7, 2, 5 3, 7, 5, 2 5, 2, 3, 7 5, 2, 7, 3 5, 3, 2, 7 5, 3, 7, 2 5, 7, 2, 3 5, 7, 3, 2 7, 2, 3, 5 7, 2, 5, 3 7, 3, 2, 5 7, 3, 5, 2 7, 5, 2, 3 7, 5, 3, 2
```

not every number is separated by a comma and neither it's a single string.
Desired output is something like this :

```
'235723752537257327'
```

Comment: `", ".join(...)`

Comment: if you what it as string with numbers `'235723752537257327'` then why do you use `"%s, %s, %s, %s"` and why do you use space in `" ".join()` ? it makes no sense.

Comment: still doesn't remove commas  ','  between the numbers.

Comment: if you want to remove commas then DON'T use commas in `"%s, %s, %s, %s"` BTW: and skip also spaces `"%s%s%s%s"` if you want result without spaces.

Comment: trying to remove the tuple brackets inside the list.

Comment: you don't have to add commas in string to remove brackets.

Comment: tried that but the results are still like: ['2357, 2375, 2537...']

Comment: And now you have to use `"".join(['2357', '2375', '2537'. ...])` to get single string.

Comment: @njzk2 NOT required. Furnas was helpful enough in correcting the problem. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: (sorry if you took that the wrong way, but I literally don't understand why you ask for help to remove something that you explicitly add yourself. I find that very confusing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`permutation` gives list like

```
[(2, 3, 5, 7), (2, 3, 7, 5), ...]
```

which you can convert to list of strings

```
['2357', '2375', '2537'. ...]
```

using

```
 "%s%s%s%s" % data
```

without commans and spaces.

And next you can use `"".join()` to convert new list to single string

```
from itertools import permutations

l = []

perm = permutations([2,3,5,7], 4)

for data in perm:
    l.append("%s%s%s%s" %data)

result = ''.join(l)

print(result)
```

The same as list comprehension

```
from itertools import permutations

perm = permutations([2,3,5,7], 4)

result = ''.join("%s%s%s%s" % data for data in perm)

print(result)
```

But this will need longer `"%s%s%s%s"` for longer permutations.

Better can be use `str()` with `for`-loop and `"".join()`

```
 "".join(str(x) for x in data)
```

in line

```
 for data in perm:
     l.append( "".join(str(x) for x in data) )
```